# Pushing and pulling from GIT failure - strange error

Tags: git

```
Clone: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error. git upload-pack: aborting due         to possible repository corruption on the remote side. early EOF index-pack failed
Cloning into 'C:\[...]'...
git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
early EOF
remote: fatal: loose object 934b66477e0a890a7060182c3e486857ec1a4238 (stored in ./objects/93/4b66477e0a890a7060182c3e486857ec1a4238) is corrupt
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
index-pack failed
```

I do not understand why I suddenly came across such a problem - everything have worked great until now. Is there anybody willing to help me?

Answer (score 0):

The repository you're trying to clone is corrupt. Why is unknown, can be a disk failure on the remote side for exmaple. I suggest you (on your remote) try to run `git fsck`. You'll probably get a list of corrupted files, replace those files with not corrupted files from your backup.

Comment: git fsck
    Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
    Checking objects: 100% (237/237), done.

So it's not the answer. ;/

Comment: In that case I think this question needs more details. Can you clone the repo locally on the remote for example?